# Get 2x same table's column 1 result

Tags: mysql, join

I have a `users` table and a `friends` table.

I want to get the friendships of 1 user, but getting both user info in results.
For example, let's say I have these tables:

```
- users (_id_, username, firstname, lastname)
- friends (_#id1, #id2_)
```

Here are some data:

```
- users (1, foo, Foo, BAR)
        (2, john, John, DOE)
- friends (1, 2)
```

If I query fiendship `WHERE id1 = 1 OR id2 = 1`, I know that with a `JOIN` I can get for each row, the user data. But how to get in 1 result (1 row) both users data?

Comment: what is desired output ?

Comment: The desired output is exactely the output given by Arion's request. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    u1.*,
    u2.*
FROM
    friends
    JOIN users AS u1
        ON friends._#id1=u1._id_
    JOIN users AS u2
        ON friends.#id2_=u2._id_
```

Comment: Thank you both of you ! I didn't know I could do like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u1.*, u2.*
FROM users u1
JOIN friends f1
ON u1._ID_ = friends._#id1_
JOIN users u2
ON u2._ID_ = friends._#id2_
```

Each row will contain all the info from one user, and then all the info from the second user. You might want to replace that first `JOIN friends f1` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN friends f1` to also display a row for users without friends.

Careful: a user with multiple friends will show multiple rows. There is no automatic way in MySQL to pivot these rows to columns. You can however `GROUP` on the `u1._ID_`, and then use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function to display the friends information.

Comment: There won't be any user in `friends`, without friends ;)
Thank you anyway !

Comment: No, but there might be a user in users, without friends. Unless you are sure this never happens in your application :]